# Android Common height and width for all resolutions

Tags: android

i am using this below code for getting drawable its works perfectly but the Height and width differ in all screen how can i get common height(size = 34) and width (size = 34) for all device ..

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        int height = 34,
                width = 34;
        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
        int id = _context.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", _context.getPackageName());
        Drawable empty = _context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, height, width);
        return d;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use density independent pixels for a common size across screen densities.

```
int dips = 34;
Resources r = getResources();
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dips, r.getDisplayMetrics());
```

and then use the equivalent pixels to set the width and height,

```
d.setBounds(0, 0, px, px);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take the device screen density in account. Use following solution.

```
public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
    int height = 34, width = 34;
    // Scale width and height based on screen density.
    int scaledHeigh = (int) Math.ceil(height * _context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    int scaledHeigh = (int) Math.ceil(height * _context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
    int id = _context.getResources().getIdentifier(source, "drawable", _context.getPackageName());
    Drawable empty = _context.getResources().getDrawable(id);
    d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
    // Use the scaled width and height.
    d.setBounds(0, 0, scaledHeight, scaledWidth);
    return d;
}
```